# Add 'Back' button to jQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I have recently adapted a jQuery Slideshow and I'm 99.2% happy with it - oh yes :)

I just wonder, **how easy is it to add a 'back' button to return to the previous slide**?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/13/

As an example, when the Slideshow loads, I'd like to click the phrase 'Text' and then click 'BACK' to return to the previous slide (the one with 'Text' on it).

Can someone explain how I achieve this?

I'm currently navigating to another "slide" by using this in my JS:
`"firstline" : "<div class=\"navigator\" id=\"navigator-2\">Text</div>",`

**It doesn't even have to go "back" - so long as clicking 'Back' navigates to 1 specific image, it'll be fine :)**

Many thanks for any pointers with this :)

Comment: What am I missing? Isn't this how your fiddle is working now? I click vacation it moves to the stock xchange I click back it goes back to the vacation slide.

Comment: Aaaah, my apologies, Rick. If you click the text phrase 'Text' initally you're taken to a new slide. Now, I'd like it when you click 'BACK' on that new slide, that you get taken to another slide. Currently it doesn't do anything.
`Please ignore the red hyperlinks`. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in, because I swear it's behaving exactly how you want it to in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of Chrome. When you click the text 'BACK', are you navigating to another Slide? It's not for me.

Comment: Another slide as in a completely new one? In that case no, it takes me back to the vacation one. But honestly that is what I would expect from a back button. If a back button didn't take me to where I previously was why would it be called back? O.o

Comment: Strange. On my computer (both Chrome & FF) clicking the 'BACK' text does nothing. Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: Is this the functionality you were attempting to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/Vtcgb/